# How to sort & concatenate multiple string values for each user per day in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have an instance where my data looks like this:

```
date       | user_id | product
2020-01-01 | 1       | banana
2020-01-01 | 1       | apple
2020-01-01 | 1       | kiwi
```

I would like to write a sql query that will output this format by compressing:

```
date       | user_id | product
2020-01-01 | 1       | apple,banana,kiwi (ordered!)
```

How would that be possible in SQL? Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is MySQL,

```
SELECT
t.date
, t.user_id
,GROUP_CONCAT(t.product ORDER BY t.product) as products
FROM
your_table_name t
GROUP BY
t.date, t.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

this query based on MSSQL for convert rows value into one comma saparate string based on group by

```
SELECT date, user_id, product = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + product
           FROM your_table b 
           WHERE b.date = a.date and b.user_id = a.user_id 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM your_table a
GROUP BY date, user_id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.